# Vertical Align images with Text

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to align the image next to the text in my code.

Please disregard how messy it is. I was doing a project for school and I didn't know how to fix this issue I'm having. 
The project isn't mandatory although it's for a competition to win a raspberry pi that I need for a future project involving bitcoins.

https://jsfiddle.net/kdn1x2hk/3/

```html
<!DOCTYPE! html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      margin-top: -11px;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .bg {
      margin-left: 20%;
      width: 60%;
      background-color: grey;
      border-left: thick solid black;
      border-right: thick solid black;
    }
    
    .background {
      background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .banner {
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: thick solid black;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      border-bottom: thick solid black;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none!important;
      font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    }
    
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: #FFD700;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .header {
      font-size: 80pt;
      font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      min-width: 80pt;
    }
    
    .dotted_line {
      border-top: 2px dashed black;
      width: 70%;
    }
    
    .paragraph {
      font-size: 15pt;
      width: 500px;
      margin-left: 0%;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .sub_header {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 50pt;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .credit {
      width: 560;
      size: 20pt;
      text-align: center;
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    .video {
      width: 70%;
      margin-left: 15%;
      border: thick solid black;
    }
    
    .credit_link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #image {
      width: 45%;
    }
    
    #text {
      width: 45%;
      float: left;
      font-size: 15pt;
      color: black;
      padding-top: 20px;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
      -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
      text-size-adjust: none;
    }
    
    .format {
      width: 90%;
      margin-left: 10%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could comment or rate the answer if it helped your query.

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/kdn1x2hk/4/

Comment: You never responded if the answer did solve your query or not, could have notified atleast if not rated it.

Answer (score 0):

Changes:

- Moved the `#text` before the `#image` inside `format class container` and used `display:flex` instead of `float:left on your #text container` to also provide vertical alignment.
- Added `align-items:center` on format class to vertically align both of its contents i.e text and image.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sbakj4x0/

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: -11px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}

.bg {
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: grey;
  border-left: thick solid black;
  border-right: thick solid black;
}

.background {
  background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: thick solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom: thick solid black;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  color: black;
}

.header {
  font-size: 80pt;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 80pt;
}

.dotted_line {
  border-top: 2px dashed black;
  width: 70%;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 15pt;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 0%;
  color: black;
}

.sub_header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50pt;
  color: black;
}

.credit {
  width: 560;
  size: 20pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
}

.video {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  border: thick solid black;
}

.credit_link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#image {
  width: 45%;
}

#text {
  width: 45%;
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
}

.format {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gsceMM5.png" class="banner">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="stats.html">Stats</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p class="header"> WELCOME</p>
      <hr class="dotted_line" />
      <p class="sub_header">What is Bitcoin?</p>
      <video class="video" poster="images/thumbnail.jpg" controls>
        <source src="videos/info.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <p class="credit">
        (Credit to <a class="credit_link" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/weusecoins">WeUseCoins</a> on youtube.com)
      </p>
      <div class="format">
        <p id="text">
          Bitcoin is a new currency that was created in 2009 by an unknown person using the alias Satoshi Nakamoto. Transactions are made with no middle men – meaning, no banks! Bitcoin can be used to book hotels on Expedia, shop for furniture on Overstock and
          buy Xbox games. But much of the hype is about getting rich by trading it. The price of bitcoin skyrocketed into the thousands in 2017.
        </p>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BGsKZms.png" id="image" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```